# Need help understanding a list container

Tags: c++, arrays, list, linked-list

I am unsure about how this linked list would look like.

```
list<string> hashTable [HASH_TABLE_SIZE];
```

I would believe that this one:

```
list<string> hashTable;
```

would look like this:

```
Head->[]->[]->[]->NULL
```

but what does

```
list<string> hashTable [HASH_TABLE_SIZE];
```

look like?

Comment: The first one isn't a linked list; its an array of linked lists. Take what you have for the single instance, and draw out multiples, each to their own array slot.

Comment: @WhozCraig is right, however you can have a linked list of linked lists.. and can nest any longer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it would look like this:

```
[Head][Head][Head]...
  ^     ^      ^
  |     |      |
  v     v      v
 [ ]   [ ]    [ ]
  ^     ^      ^
  |     |      |
  v     v      v
 NULL  NULL   NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

That is an array of std::list's of std::string's, a std::list can be iterated both forwards and backwards, so it is really a doubly linked list.  That looks more like the picture below

each:

```
hashTable[index]:

  begin()-*          *-rbegin()
          |          |
          v          v
  rend()<-[]<->[]<->[]->end()

/* walk index'th list in hashTable in forward order and print it out */
int f = 0;
list<string>::iterator fwdItr = hashTable[index].begin();
for (; fwdItr != hashTable[index].end(); ++f, ++fwdItr)
{
    printf("fwd list entry %d = %s\n", f, *fwdItr);
}


/* walk index'th list in hashTable in reverse order and print it out */
int r = 0;
list<string>::reverse_iterator revItr = hashTable[index].rbegin();
for (; revItr != hashTable[index].rend(); ++r, ++revItr)
{
    printf("rev list entry %d = %s\n", r, *revItr);
}
```

hope this helps illustrate std::list a bit better...